# angularjs run function from element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What I want to do, is set a star rating system, that can be adjusted.
Involves an HTTP request, so we will call the js object "data" and the required value is "rating". code is something like this (subsisting classes for fontawesome and bootstrap):

```
    <style>
      .blue{background:blue}
    </style>
    
   <div ng-controller="Controller as ctrl">
    <div ng-repeat="objects in ctrl.data">
           <button ng-repeat="star in [1,2,3,4,5]" ng-class={'blue': star <= {{ objects.ratings }} }</button>
     </div>
   </div>
```

This will show me the ratings in blue buttons.

Now I want to add an ng-click that will change the rating to what I push. So I would need to replace the binding with a variable ('rating'), and the ng-click to change the value of rating.

So basically I want to run a function at the creation of each ng-repeat div, that will start with the value of objects.ratings but can change via ng-click to it scope value.
So How can I run a function while creating an element?

Comment: So what is your specific problem and question? So far you have only given a casual outline of a goal, but no specifics on where you are having code related issues accomplishing that goal. Might be a good time to thoroughly read [ask]

Comment: And since you know you need an `ng-click` what have you tried?

Comment: the only thing that worked was to POST the change of value of objects.ratings, which is not what i want to do.
theme that did not work: setting ng-class based on a function that called a variable with the value of objects.ratings, and ng-click to change the value of variable.

Comment: Not 100% clear where you are running into issues without a [mcve] and more specific details showing where you are stuck